# Error Handling in GIF download script

Tags: ruby, json, error-handling

I'm in the process of learning to program so I've been coming up with some random projects. I decided to make a script that downloads all of the GIF's I've collected over the past few years. Everything seems to be working except an error I receive half way through that my error handling doesn't catch (invalid access mode "wb", "ArgumentError URI:HTTP resource is read only). I've been fiddling for over a day and can't get this work any help or tips would be appreciated.

```
require 'json', 'open-uri'    
def download

file = open("C:/sites/bookmark/gifs.json")
json = file.read

parsed = JSON.parse(json)

gifs = parsed["children"]
file.close()
total = 0
gifsize = 0
    gifs.each do |key|

        source = "#{key["uri"]}"
        source.chomp
        gifname = "#{key["title"]}"
        gifname.gsub(/[^0-9a-z ]/i, '')
        open("#{gifname}.gif", "wb") do |file|

            begin
              open(source)                  
            rescue Exception => e
                case e.message
                    when /404/ then puts '404!' 
                    when /505/ then puts '505!'
                    when /408/ then puts '408!'
                    else puts 'idk #{e.message}'
                end
                file.close()
                File.delete("#{gifname}.gif")
                puts "Deleted #{key["title"]}.gig"
                next
            end

            open(source) do |uri|

                file.write(uri.read)
                total += 1
                gifsize += (uri.size / 1024)
                print "#{(uri.size)/1024} KiloBytes"
            end
            print " --- #{total}"
        end
        puts " next gif---"
    end
    puts "\n#{gifsize} Total KB Downloaded \n#{total} Total Gifs "

end

download()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `gifname.gsub(/[^0-9a-z ]/i, '')` doesn't actually do anything, because the method `String#gsub` does not modify the String, but returns a modificated one.
You need to use `String#gsub!` instead:
`gifname.gsub!(/[^0-9a-z ]/i, '')`

Because of that, `gifname` is probably a HTTP URL, and `open-uri` cannot open it in write mode, as the error message states.

In order to debug this kind of problem, you should run ruby debugger, or put a bunch of `puts` statements to check the content of your variables.

Comment: It worked, Thanks a lot! I was unaware of what adding a '!' did to gsub.

Comment: This is a common Ruby idiom a lot of methods use. When developing, debug statements and the Ruby Doc (http://www.ruby-doc.org/) are your best friends.